# cfchart x axis intervals

Tags: coldfusion, cfchart, coldfusion-10

I have created a cfchart in CF10 that has 168 data points - i.e. one for each hour of a week. The issue I am having is that the x axis labels are a little all over the place depending on how wide I make the chart e.g. At the moment they are

```
1,4,7,14,22,30,38...103,115,127,129,151,168
```

which isn't all that intuitive for the end-user. Is there any way to define specific intervals to display instead? For example, ideally I would like the intervals to be:

```
0,24,48,72...168
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to do this by building your own custom chart XML using the WebCharts java app that comes with ColdFusion, but there is no way to do this with the built-in attributes of the cfchart tags. There are several [articles](http://www.cfinsider.com/index.cfm/2009/11/25/Complex-Charting-in-ColdFusion-with-WebCharts) online (search for [ColdFusion Webcharts](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=coldfusion%20webcharts&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)) that can show you how to get started with custom charting.

Comment: Thanks Dan, that did the trick. I had to modify the relevant XML file as follows:  <pre><code><xAxis type="Scale" scaleMin="1" scaleMax="168" labelCount="8"></code></pre>